# Is the set of conjugates of Pisot numbers dense?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of Pisot numbers. It is known that $S$ is closed and has infinitely many limit points. However, I want to know if there are are results about the set of conjugates of Pisot numbers. In particular, do we know if the set of conjugates of Pisot numbers is dense in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ (unit disk+ unit circle) or is it an open problem?

Comment: @Ville Salo - Yes. I can't find any result regarding  the set of conjugates at all.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb but aren't Pisot numbers a closed set so not dense since not all reals are Pisot, and conjugates have small modulus.

Comment: I am being dumb/blind, dense in unit disk!

Comment: @Ville Salo - Correct. But I am concerned with the set of nontrivial conjugates. Maybe I should have said that by 'conjugates', I meant the nontrivial conjugates.